# PackageManager does not work on Android 2.3.4

Tags: android, youtube, android-package-managers

I am launching the default Youtube App installed on device to play a video. First, I want to check if the app exists on the device using PackageManager.

If the app does not exists, I want to redirect the user to the Google Play to download the app.

Below is the code snippet:

```
    String appName = "com.google.android.youtube";
    Boolean existFlg = false;
    Context context = getApplicationContext();      

    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    // get all installed app's info
    List<PackageInfo> pinfo = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
    for (int i = 0; i < pinfo.size(); i++) {
        String name = pinfo.get(i).packageName;
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(appName)) {
            existFlg = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (existFlg) {
        // start Youtube Native App
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:"+video_id));
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
    }               
    // not installed
    else {
        // goto the market to download Youtube App
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.youtube");
        Intent market = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        market.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        try {
            context.startActivity(market);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            // if market app not exist, goto the web of Google Play to download the Facebook App
            String googleURL = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube";
            Uri googleplay_webpage = Uri.parse(googleURL);
            Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, googleplay_webpage);
            marketIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(marketIntent);
        }
    }
```

This code works perfectly well on **Android 4.0.4** and above. But when I am trying to run it on **Android 2.3.4** it ALWAYS redirects the user to the Google Play irrespective of whether the App is installed or not.

Any idea as to how to make this compatible with Android 2.3.4 too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably because `PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES` doesn't really make much sense here? 
You probably want something like:

```
try {
  PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo("com.google.android.youtube", 0);
  // start Youtube
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
  // go to Play Store
}
```

Also a better approach would be not to force the Youtube app on the user, but simply use the VIEW action and let them choose the app they want to use.

Comment: Also, I agree that forcing the user to use the Youtube app is not a good idea...but in this case it's because of a specific requirement